# Se puede retirar un método de una clase dado a un objeto?

Tags: javascript

La pregunta creo que es simple
Tengo un objeto:

```
var pW = new Pawn()
```

y en la clase Pawn tengo un método,
hago:

```
pW.checkAvailable()
```

Hasta aquí okay, ahora ejecuto el método checkAvailable() de la clase Pawn en el nuevo objeto pW.

el checkAvailable me pinta un cuadrado.

Hay alguna manera de poder "deshacer" el `.checkAvailable()`?

como un `pW.cancel(checkAvailable())` para que el pW ya no dibuje la pieza?

No sé si me he explicado

Comment: ¿Cómo que "deshacer"? ¿Quieres "deshacer" el cuadro pintado en consola, o el pintado en un `<canvas>`, o el que pintas con un brazo electrónico y un pincel en un lienzo físico al invocar esa función? Por favor, específica a qué te refieres con "deshacer" y con "pintar"

Answer (score 1):

Puedes declarar una variable `wasAvailabilityChecked` como miembro de la clase `Pawn` y ponerla en `false`.

Al principio del método `checkAvailable`, realiza la validación:

```
if (this.wasAvailabilityChecked) return;
```

Al final de este método cambia el valor de `wasAvailabilityChecked` para `true`:

```
this.wasAvailabilityChecked = true;
```

Espero haberte ayudado.